# Programmatically setting Look And Feel, post startup

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, netbeans-platform

I know I can change the L&F before startup using my app.conf file, but I would prefer to avoid that since Netbeans fails to have individual app.conf files for each individual RCP application, and I have a few that will NOT use thte target Look And Feel.

I can do this:

```
LookAndFeel hifi = new HiFiLookAndFeel();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(hifi);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
```

But that only updates the current component, not the toolbars, windows etc.  Is there another way to solve my dilemma WITHOUT having to swap my app.conf files on each build?

I woul like to set the look and feel and have the entire application change, but NOT modify my app.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it.

Generate a new *ModuleInstall* class, under the *New->Other->Module Development->Installer/Activator* menu.

It will register that class to be run during startup (specifically the *Restored()* method).

Put your LookAndFeel altering code in that method and you are good to go.

NOTE: This was done with Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);`  Replace `this` with a reference to the top-level component you want to update (such as the JFrame of your application).  Repeat as necessary for any other top-level components in your application (i.e. if you have multiple JFrames in use)

Comment: The issue is that getting a reference to every component the Netbeans RCP creates is very hard -- I just loaded it programatically with other modules and every item uses the new L&F

Comment: @Andrew-Thompson Thompson Instead of talking down to me, please help me find the way to do it.  While searching today, I found no ability to  go beyond the current TopComponent (which is just an editor pane).  I could do a lookup by class type, but that is pure bruteforcing that  should not be done.  Changing this left every bit of the rest of the application at the old look and feel, which looks atrocious.

Comment: @AndrewThompson where did you get *JEditorPane*?  This is RCP specific terminology.  It is a TopComponent in the Editor position.  Again, please be more friendly and less derisive.